# Silent printing from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I would like to disable this printing dialog:
[image: dialog]

What should I do to remove this dialog?

```
var dlg = new PrintDialog();
dlg.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
dlg.UserPageRangeEnabled = false;
var doc = new FlowDocument();
    doc.PageWidth = 275;
    doc.FontSize = 18;
    doc.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("nXXXXXXXXXXXX")));
dlg.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator, "Receipt");
```

Comment: hi check out this https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8628/how-to-silent-print-the-report-without-using-print-dialog#:~:text=The%20silent%20printing%20of%20report,formats%20without%20rendering%20in%20preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PrintDocument class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `PrintDialog`.See the Microsoft's implementation

```
    try
    {
        streamToPrint = new StreamReader
           ("C:\\My Documents\\MyFile.txt");
        try
        {
            printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
               (this.pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();
        }
        finally
        {
            streamToPrint.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```