# Print PDF without print window popping up, if there already is a default printer

Tags: .net, printing, maui, point-of-sale

I have a POS system, it will create a pdf that is similar to a bill receipt. and also there is an option as a button to print it. I need to print the pdf without popping up the print window with the already selected printer if there is a default printer. Otherwise, it has to pop up a window to choose a printer.
I created this app using MAUI (.net) framework.

Need to implement that print system without popping up the window

Comment: What kind of device is your app running on?

Comment: Also: the print window does A LOT more than just select a printer. It can also pick things like which input or output tray, whether to duplex, staple, hole punch, or other finishing, should it do any scaling or water marks, etc. I do understand if you want to simplify things, but if you're really confident the users will NEVER want to use those features, then you also don't want to show the print window even when they have multiple printers, and instead just show a list of printers to choose from.

Comment: The device is Windows.

Comment: If you could provide the full program source of an example that shows the print dialog and print it, or a link to that repository, it would be easier to get advice and answers from a wider audience. For example there are these articles for print but not MAUI. [Silently Printing PDF Documents in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1134699/Silently-Printing-PDF-Documents-in-Csharp), [Silent printing from WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66276967/9014308), [How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6103705/9014308)